# Python set difference not working

Tags: python

In the following code;

```
all_digits = set(range(10))
print all_digits
for i in range(102,167):
    digits = set(k for k in (str(i)))
    if len(digits) != 3:
        continue
    print "digits:", digits
    remaining_digits = all_digits - digits
    print "remaining:", remaining_digits
```

The digits set contains 3 elements. I want a set difference of them, however, `remaining_digits` always have all digits. What am I doing wrong here?
Here is a sample from output I am getting;

```
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '2'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '3'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '4'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '5'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '6'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '7'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
digits: set(['1', '0', '8'])
remaining: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`all_digits` is a set of the ten integers `0` through `9`, whereas `digits` is a set of 1-character strings like `"0"`.  Since the types are different, the set difference doesn't work as expected.

To make it work like you want, either use all integers or use all strings, e.g.:

```
all_digits = set(map(str, range(10)))
```

Comment: Ahh, such a rookie mistake. Sorry for taking your time.